# Removing the AFNetworking framework after installation through pods giving linker error

Tags: ios, swift

I had installed AFNetworking framework through pods, then Removed pods. Manually added AFNetworking folders. Now I am getting the below error.

ld: framework not found AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The project is in Swift and the AFNetworking is in iOS

Comment: clean - re install pods

Comment: now I am not using pods, removed

Comment: did you run `pod deintegrate`?

Comment: yes, but no luck